# FactoryGirl + Rspec custom validation test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm pretty new to testing.

I have a custom validation at my Profile model

```
def birth_date_cannot_be_in_the_future
    errors.add(:birth_date, "the birth date cannot be in the future") if
    !birth_date.blank? && birth_date > Date.today
end
```

At my factories.rb

```
sequence(:email) {|n| "person-#{n}@example.com"}
factory :user do
  email
  password 'password'
  password_confirmation 'password'
  confirmed_at Time.now
end

factory :profile do
  user
  first_name { "User" }
  last_name { "Tester" }
  birth_date { 21.years.ago }
end
```

At my models/profile_spec.rb

```
it 'birth date cannot be in the future' do
    profile = FactoryGirl.create(:profile, birth_date: 100.days.from_now)
    expect(profile.errors[:birth_date]).to include("the birth date cannot be in the future")
    expect(profile.valid?).to be_falsy
end
```

When I run my test I receive the follow message:

```
Failure/Error: profile = FactoryGirl.create(:profile, birth_date: 100.days.from_now)

 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   The validation fails: Birth date the birth date cannot be in the future
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a matcher just for catching errors. Without having tested, I'm assuming you can go:

```
expect { FactoryGirl.create(:profile, birth_date: 100.days.from_now) }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

Another approach though is to include the `shoulda` gem, which has the `allow_value` matcher. This lets you do something more like this in your model spec:

```
describe Profile, type: :model do
  describe 'Birth date validations' do
    it { should allow_value(100.years.ago).for(:birth_date) }
    it { should_not allow_value(100.days.from_now).for(:birth_date) }
  end
end
```

Generally you wont need FactoryGirl at all when you're testing things like validations. They become super useful in controller tests though.

Just put assertions for your model in a model spec, which tests your model code directly. These usually live in `spec/models/model_name_spec.rb` There are convenient shoulda matchers for a bunch of common model stuff:

```
describe SomeModel, type: :model do
  it { should belong_to(:user) }
  it { should have_many(:things).dependent(:destroy) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:type) }
  it { should validate_length_of(:name).is_at_most(256) }
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:code).allow_nil }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be using `build` instead of `create`

Also `profile.valid?` should be called before checking `profile.errors`

```
it 'birth date cannot be in the future' do
  profile = FactoryGirl.build(:profile, birth_date: 100.days.from_now)
  expect(profile.valid?).to be_falsy
  expect(profile.errors[:birth_date]).to include("the birth date cannot be in the future")
end
```

Comment: `expect(profile.valid?).to be_falsy` can be rewritten as `expect(profile).to be_valid`